# Need help to get value from Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

Table 1

```
Name      City
--------------------
Deep      Delhi
Manu      Atlanta
Raju      PanamaCity
```

Table 2

```
City
-----
Delhi
```

I wanted to add another column called "Country" in the results so the final results would be like

```
Name      City          Country
-------------------------------
Deep      Delhi         Known
Manu      Atlanta       Unknown
Raju      PanamaCity    Unknown
```

So if the value of city column of first table is a match then new column's value should have "Known"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please take a moment to review all the information about how to ask a good question here - your current question does not meet the guidelines, and will soon be closed if you don't fix it.  http://stackoverflow.com/help and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions will help.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) and case statements

```
SELECT t1.name, 
  t2.city, 
  case t2.city is NULL then 'Unknown' else 'Known' end as Country
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
 on t1.city = t2.city
```

Mockup:

```
Select t1.name, 
  t1.city, 
  case when t2.city is NULL then 'Unknown' else 'Known' end as Country 
FROM (
  select 'Deep' as Name, 'Dehli' as city from dual UNION
  select 'Manu' as Name, 'Atlanta' as city from dual UNION
  select 'Raju' as Name, 'PanamaCity' as city from dual) t1
LEFT JOIN 
(select 'Dehli' as city from dual) 
  t2
  on t1.city=t2.city

results in:
Name    City        Country
Deep    Dehli       Known
Manu    Atlanta     Unknown
Raju    PanamaCity  Unknown
```

Comment: Thank you very for your help. Its exactly same thing what I was trying to do.